# Cannot start tensorboard in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tensorboard

I am trying to start tensorboard in Jupyter Notebook:

```
%load_ext tensorboard
%tensorboard --logdir runs
```

But I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Timed out waiting for TensorBoard to start. It may still be running as pid 28048.
```

I can start tensorboard from console, but can't get it through Jupyter Notebook. I am installing only tensorboard (no tensorflow) and it is installed in my base environment. I am using Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Managed to solve it! I used conda to install tensorboard, and it installed version 1.15. Uninstalled it and reinstalled using pip so it installed version 2.5 which resolves the issue in response to [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/pull/4407)

Answer (score 1):

May try the following if other methods don't work:

```
pip install -U tb-nightly
```